# How to Get Variable from another .py

Tags: python, return, pygtk

I have two .py programme. I call second .py program , the second program solves a problem . So ı want to get that solution to first one and use . for example:

1.py:

call 2.py

y= x+2

2.py:

x = 2+2

Comment: There is a python routine called pickle that might help with that, but I believe that the receiving code has to know to pick up the pickled variable. Can you post the code that you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `subprocess` module and create a pipe. Then you can pickle the variable and send it through the pipe (see documentation of [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess)).

Here is an example:

module for communication `communicate.py`:

```
import sys
import subprocess as sp
import cPickle

BEGIN = 'pickle_begin'

def send_and_exit(x):
    sys.stdout.write(BEGIN + cPickle.dumps(x))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.exit(0)

def execute_and_receive(filename):
    p = sp.Popen(["python", filename], stdout=sp.PIPE)
    (out, err) = p.communicate()
    return cPickle.loads(out[out.find(BEGIN) + len(BEGIN):])
```

`1.py`:

```
from communicate import *
x = execute_and_receive("2.py")
y = x + 2
```

`2.py`:

```
from communicate import *
x = 2 + 2
send_and_exit(x)
```

To make sure, you start unpickling at the correct point of the `stdout` stream I recommend to set a marker, like I did with the `BEGIN` string. Probably there are more elegant solutions, if so, I'm interested as well.

Comment: ıt is a bit complicated , isnt there any other chance to do that , ı just send value one .py to another .

Comment: At least there will be no single python statement, since you need some kind of interprocess communication. You could of course wrap the above  code into some functions allowing you to call something like `send_and_return(x)` in the child and `x = execute_and_receive('name.py')` from the parent.

Comment: do you have a tutorial of the what u mention above ? I must read to handle

Comment: (Edited answer.) If you have questions after reading the subprocess module docs, feel free to ask, which part of the example remains unclear.

Comment: ı couldnt manage to get value , from child to parent .ı must get a value "x" and use x in function at parent. thats my main problem. also thank u for understanding

Comment: y=subprocess.Popen(["python","/home/emeks/workspace/ex/ex.py"])
print y
this command call ex.py and ı want to get x value from ex.py and
print y 

but when ı run the program there is a sign " <subprocess.Popen object at 0x8b0214c>"
like that

Comment: I did not quite get, what you want to do from the last two comments. Probably edit your question (remove all the gtk stuff, since it seems not to be related to your question) and explain, why the given answer is not what you are looking for or why it is not satisfactory. From the last comments it is not clear what `ex.py` should do and why the proposed method does not work.

Comment: Good update, nice and clear question form which other people can profit as well!

Comment: Ive done what u answered above . but it didnt work , anyway thank u for everthing

Comment: If you just copy the given examples into files and run `python -i 1.py` then type `y` and it should print `6`. If not, feel free to explain what the error is. Anyway, it is a good question I was thinking of myself some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the .py file into another file
Running it in OS does not get the variable in your new file

Use

```
from module import function
```

You can then call the function from this new file and print the value that it returns

Comment: how can ı use that . could u give example ?

Comment: But then it runs in the same process, which you do not always want. For example, if the submodule does memory intensive stuff and you want to make sure that the allocated memory goes back to the system afterwards. If you do the import, it is not guaranteed that the python heap manager will give all the memory back to the system.

Comment: do you have tutorial of what u mention above ?